# Show convergence of $a_n=\frac{n^3}{n^3+n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, limits-without-lhopital

I have $a_n=\frac{n^3}{n^3+n}$. I have to show it's convergent with limiting value 1.
If we use our rules then we get:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^3}{n^3+n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{n^3}{n^3}}{\frac{n^3}{n^3}+\frac{n}{n^3}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{n}{n^3}}=1.$$
But how do I show convergence here?

Comment: you show convergence by showing that it satisfies the definition that is being used for convergence, by doing some epsilon delta hickory pockery.

Comment: I tried to format yout post, but can't see what you are trying to do , look at my edit and try to fix the rest yourself.

Comment: I can find "hickory pockery" in my dictionary. What does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

$|a_n-1|=\frac n {n^{3}+n} <\frac  1 {n^{2}} <\epsilon$ if $n >\frac 1 {\sqrt {\epsilon}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Prove that $a_{n} = \frac{n^{3}}{n^{3}+n} = \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n^{2}}}$ is increasing, which guarantees $a_{n}$ tends to $\sup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_{n}$,since it's bounded, then show that it's supremum is 1.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x}$ is continuous at $0$ so
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n 
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^3}{n^3+n} 
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n^2}} 
= \frac{1}{1+\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}} 
= \frac{1}{1+0} 
= 1
.
$$